# convert PDF to SVG with inkscape via node.js

Tags: node.js, inkscape

Hello I'm using inkscape Module to convert pdf to svg and why I'm Getting `Cannot read property 'end' of undefined`

**My Code:**

```
const Inkscape = require('inkscape');

const pdfToSvgConverter = new Inkscape([
  '--export-plain-svg',
  '--import-pdf',
  '--export-text-to-path'
]);


fs.createReadStream('test/people.pdf').pipe(pdfToSvgConverter).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./out.svg'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Inkscape version 1.0 or above, it's likely because the module doesn't support that yet. They completely changed the CLI switches.